# When is $A\otimes R$ a free $R$-module?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If I am not mistaken, there is the following fact:

> For a finitely generated abelian group $A$, the $R$-module $A\otimes R$ is free if and only if we can write the torsion part of $A$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}/k$, where $k$ is invertible or zero in $R$

While elementary, I found this surprisingly tricky to prove and my proof takes about half a page. But I assume, this fact should be known. As I need it for a paper of mine, I want to ask whether someone knows a reference for it. In absence of a reference, I would also be happy with a slick 5-line proof!

Comment: Half a page seems reasonable. There are little subtleties: e.g., for $R=\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}$ (which is somewhat a degenerate case, since all its modules are projective), and denoting by $C_k$ the cyclic group of order $k$, $A\otimes R$ is free for $A=C_2\times C_3$ but not for $C_2\times C_3^2$.

Comment: If you had asked when the module is projective the answer would be much cleaner, because projectivity is preserved and reflected by direct sums ($M = \bigoplus M_i$ is projective iff each $M_i$ is projective), but freeness isn't reflected. After tinkering for a bit I agree that half a page is reasonable.

Comment: @Qiaochu: if you replace "free" by "projective", the question boils down to: for which primes $p$, integer $m\ge 1$, and commutative ring $R$, is $R/p^kR$ a projective module? What do you call a "much cleaner answer" in this case? I don't see how to do without referring to decomposition of $R$ as a product.

Comment: $R/nR$ is a projective $R$-module iff the map $R \to R/nR$ splits iff $(n) = (n^2)$ in $R$.

Comment: ... iff $nR$ is generated by an idempotent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a 7-line proof of your statement.

> > **Claim.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1_R$. Let $A \simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_k\mathbb{Z}$ be a finitely generated Abelian group given with its invariant factor decomposition, i.e., $d_i \ge 0, d_i \neq 1$ and $d_i$ divides $d_{i + 1}$ for every $1 \le i \le k - 1$ (*note that $d_i = 0$ is allowed*).
> >
> > Then $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ is free over $R$ if and only if either $d_i 1_R$ is zero or a unit of $R$ for every $i$.
> >
> > *Proof (7 lines)*. Let $M \Doteq A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \simeq 
> > R/d_1 R \oplus \cdots \oplus R/d_k R$. If $d_i 1_R$ is zero or a unit of $R$ for every $i$, then $M$ is clearly free over $R$. Assume now that $M$ is free over $R$. We reason by contradiction and consider the smallest $j \ge 1$ such that $d_j 1_R$ is neither zero nor a unit. Then we have  $M \simeq R/d_j R \oplus \cdots \oplus R/d_k R$. Considering $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ which contains $d_jR$, we see that the minimal number of generators of $M$ over $R$ is $s \Doteq k -j + 1$. Therefore $M \simeq R^s$ and consequently $d_jM$ cannot be generated by less than $s$ elements. As $d_jM \simeq 
> > (d_jR/d_{j + 1} R) \oplus \cdots \oplus (d_jR/d_k R)$, we get a contradiction.

You may turn the above proof into a one-liner if you refer to this more general result of Irving Kaplansky [1, Theorem 9.3].

> > **Kaplansky's Theorem.** 
> >     Let $R$ be a ring in which every one-sided ideal is two-sided. In particular, $R$ may be any commutative ring. Suppose the $R$-module $M$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of cyclic modules $R/S_1, \dots, R/S_m$, and also to the direct sum of $R/T_1, \dots, R/T_n$, where $S_i,\, T_¡$ are ideals each containing its successor, $S_1, T_1\neq R$. Then $m = n$ and $S_i = T_i$ for all $i$.

---

**Addendum.** I found the discussion of Qiaochu Yuan and YCor about projective modules (see comments above) particularly enlightening. This is why I would like to assemble all its fragments here.

> > **Qiaochu Yuan's Claim on projectives.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $A$ be a direct sum of cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}/k_i\mathbb{Z}$ where $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $i$ ranges in some arbitrary set.
> >     Then $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ is a projective module over $R$ if and only if $k_iR = k_i^2R$ for every $i$.
> >
> > *Proof.* Let $M \Doteq A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \simeq 
> > \bigoplus_i R/k_i R$. Then $M$ is projective over $R$ if and only if $R/k_iR$ is projective for every $k$. This holds if and only if the natural map $R \twoheadrightarrow R/k_iR$ splits for every $i$, which is in turn equivalent to the fact that $k_iR$ is an idempotent ideal. As observed by YCor, $k_iR$ is generated by an idempotent in this case, see e.g, [2, Exercise 2.1], a classical application of Nakayama's lemma.

If $\mathbb{Z}1_R \simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n > 1$, then 
the condition $\text{gdc}(k, n) = \text{gdc}(k^2, n)$, or equivalently $\text{gcd}(k, \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(n, k)}) = 1$, implies $kR = k^2R$. This is certainly a necessary condition when $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

YCor outlined the fact that **every** module over $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is projective. He further extends this remark by mentioning below that every module over a commutative ring $R$ with identity is projective if and only if $R$ is the direct product of finitely many fields, see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62464/rings-with-all-modules-projective) for references and a more general statement.

> > **Remark on projective modules over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> - The integer $n$ has no square factor.
> - Every module over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is projective.
>
> > *Proof*. By the [first Prüfer Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group), a module over $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a direct sum of cyclic factors $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ where $k$ divides $n$. If $n$ is square-free, any such factor is projective over $R$ by Qiaochu Yuan's Claim. Hence any module over $R$ is projective. If $n$ has a square factor $k^2$ with $k > 1$, then $R/kR$ is not projective over $R$ by Qiaochu Yuan's Claim.

---

[1] I. Kaplansky, "Elementary divisors and modules", 1949.
[2] H. Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory", 1986.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! May I include this in my paper, of course with proper attribution to you?

Comment: It's an additional half-line, but the contradiction comes with $d_jM\simeq (d_jR/d_{j+1}R)\oplus\cdots\oplus (d_jR/d_kR)$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I followed your advice in my last edit. Another thing which might not be crystal clear at first sight: $d_j R\simeq R/I$ for some proper ideal $I$. Thus $d_jR^s$ surjects onto $(R/\mathfrak{m})^s$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ containing $I$. As a result, $d_jR^s$ cannot be generated by less than $s$ elements. It has been omitted because it is too similar to a previous observation.

Comment: @LennartMeier Sure, I'll be honored!

Comment: We can ignore the $d_i$ such that $d_i$ is a unit, but the $d_i$ such that $d_i$ is zero give summands isomorphic to $R$ so I don't see how you're ignoring them. (Although I think the argument goes through either way.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't ignore them. But the $R$-factors can only arise for $i > j$ and $R/d_jR$ is of *mixed type* by definition. (Hopefully it is relevant to your question.)

Comment: @LennartMeier You may prefer I. Kaplansky's Theorem (see last edit), should it match your needs

Comment: I didn't claim what you call "YCor's claim" (which is true and an easy particular case of the fact that for a commutative ring $A$, every $A$-module is projective iff $A$ is a finite product of fields, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62464/)

Comment: @YCor (1) You claimed that every module over $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is projective, which I found of interesting. I presumed you knew much more, which turns out to be true. I turned the claim into an anonymous remark. Please edit as you desire. (2) Thanks, you are totally right! I retracted my sentence.